# Best practice to monitor Ubuntu Server

Tags: monitor, system, system-monitor, system-info

I have an Ubuntu Server that is intermittently rebooting. I notice the reboot once every 3 weeks or so. I have a feeling that this is occurring more often and I want to get an accurate picture of the problem and how often it is occurring.

I was thinking about configuring an email that would be sent on server boot, but I wanted to ask the question here to see what is the best practice for monitoring servers. Noticed that you can configure server to send email by using Bootmail or by script using cron. I also noticed Nagios, but that seems a bit more complicated and detailed. What is the best practice for monitoring Ubuntu Servers? I am looking for something simple but yet flexible and powerful. The less shell scripting the better.

Comment: How about Hobbit? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/hobbit.7.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tools To Monitor Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111667/tools-to-monitor-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score 0):

this is the list of Linux monitoring tools: (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html). As you can see, there is Nagios as well. You did not specified the services you want to monitor.

If you need a log reader, you can try Splunk, which is free for small amount of log data. For web-server I would choose one of the many web-stat programs. Hope this will help. For database you need to monitor free disk space, tablespace sizes and CPU overloads. For simple fileserver I would choose just mail-ping (cron job is sending email/sms to your mobile.)

There are many levels of monitoring, so this much depend of what is the service your server offers, on SLA you need to reach and money you can spend.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SeaLion](https://sealion.com) it's a free linux monitoring system. You just have to install an agent program and that's it. It can monitor any custom commands, shell scripts, log output etc...
It helped me a lot when I was in situation where need to find out what went wrong at specific time on my Ubuntu server? I can easily figure out which processes were running at that time which caused high CPU, Memory and I/O wait. I recommend this tool for it's intuitiveness and ease of installation and setup.