# Tools To Monitor Ubuntu Server?

Tags: monitoring

I am looking for Web-Based tools to monitor Ubuntu Server ( disk space , ram , etc )

### +

#### apache2

### +

#### asterisk (optional)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [Webmin](http://webmin.com/) [Screenshots of Webmin](http://webmin.com/demo.html)

[Modules](http://webmin.com/standard.html)

[Usermin](http://webmin.com/usermin.html)

[Cloudmin](http://webmin.com/cloudmin.html)

Debian package suitable for Debian, Ubuntu or other derived Linux
http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.580_all.deb 14.8 MB

### This is as complete as you can get

Answer (score 2):

I would look at Munin which is available as package and generates historical graphs which can be useful when you thing things have changed.